# Cannot connect to Wordpress database after installing Wordpress on Google Cloud

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

This morning I installed Wordpress on Compute Engine on Google Cloud. But I am not able to connect to the Wordpress site. I got the login info and when I logged in, there was the Wordpress dashboard. But as soon as I clicked a menu item, it said the database was not connected.

I followed the instructions in a video, but when I pressed SSH to connect to SQL, I did not get the same option as the video instructor had. I don't know if that is what caused the error.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Did you complete the Wordpress setup? We will need a lot more information to help you. You should move this question here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ Also read this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: After I had installed it and logged in, when I clicked on a menu item I got an error message saying the database is not connected. It may have something to do with the SQL. When I clicked on SSH in the deployment manager, I chose "Open in browser window using provided private SSH key", which was not the option offered in the video I watched that said choose Cloud Shell Terminal. 

I changed the SQL password in the private SSH key window. It wasn't until afterwards when I went back to the dashboard that I saw the option I should have used, the Cloud Shell Terminal. Maybe this is the cause?

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information about what the issue is, as per your description it seems the database is not running.
I recommend you review this [article](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-error-establishing-a-database-connection-in-wordpress/) about most common issues related to establishing a database connection in WordPress.

On the other hand, take a look at the click-to-deploy WordPress solutions from the Google Cloud [MarketPlace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/). There are easy solutions to deploy all necessary WordPress packages (database included) to Compute Engine. 
[Here](https://onepagezen.com/setup-wordpress-google-cloud-platform-click-to-deploy/) a guide.

Comment: After I installed Wordpresst and logged in, when I clicked on a menu item I got an error message saying the database is not connected. It may have something to do with the SQL root. When I clicked on SSH in the deployment manager, I chose "Open in browser window using provided private SSH key", which was not the option offered in the video I watched that said choose Cloud Shell Terminal. 

I changed the SQL password in the private SSH key window. It wasn't until afterwards when I went back to the dashboard that I saw the option I should have used, the Cloud Shell Terminal. Maybe this is why?

Comment: Cloud Shell is a Google Compute Engine virtual machine with interactive shell environment for Google Cloud Platform which has a linux distribution and Cloud SDK gcloud command-line tool to manage your projects and resources from your web browser. Cloud Shell instances are provisioned on a per-user, per-session basis.
'Open in browser window using provided private SSH key' allows you access to your Compute Engine Instance(where WordPress tools were deployed) through SSH protocol by using a private SSH key.
So both (Cloud Shell and SSH Window) have nothing to do with the database.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps I can just delete the site and start over? For the video I watched said to change the SQL root password, while other sites don't mention that at all. I cannot find an up-to-date video that can show me how to set up my site on Google Cloud.

Comment: Changing default passwords is a best security practice.
Here there some useful step-by-step guides to install WP on GCP with bitnami tools:

https://docs.bitnami.com/google/get-started-marketplace/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cG9kv5-5bPI